# How to create matrix nxn with unique values and no consecutive sequence in python?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to figure out create nxn matrix with values range from 0 to n^2.
There must be no sequence in the row and column, except for n < 5.

Here's an example of the exected output:

```
array([[ 8, 13, 39,  1, 22, 37,  2],
       [ 6, 26, 36,  3, 29, 35, 16],
       [18, 20, 46, 28, 15, 12, 43],
       [ 7, 24, 14, 41, 32, 21, 27],
       [34, 31,  9, 44, 30, 48, 45],
       [11, 33, 40, 10, 38,  0,  5],
       [17, 23,  4, 19, 25, 47, 42]])
```

Comment: @Timus sorry I am new in here and python, and I have updated my post. appreciated yours comment, just tell me what else should i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your values, select randomly without replaced (or use shuffle) and reshape the array.

```
import numpy as np

# dimension
n = 5
values = np.arange(0, n**2)

# randomly selected (or use shuffle)
selected = np.random.choice(values, size = n * n, replace = False)

# reshape array to matrix
matrix = np.reshape(selected, (n, n))

array([[21,  5, 12, 23,  4],
       [13, 10, 19, 22, 20],
       [ 7,  2, 15, 18, 17],
       [ 0, 16,  6,  8, 24],
       [11,  1,  9, 14,  3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a possible solution:

```
import random
import pprint

number_rows_columns = 5
number_list = [i for i in range(number_rows_columns**2)]

final_matrix = []
for row in range(number_rows_columns):
    new_column = []
    for column in range(number_rows_columns):
        new_column.append(random.choice(number_list))
        number_list.remove(new_column[-1])
    final_matrix.append(new_column)
pprint.pprint(final_matrix)
```

A sample output of this code:

```
[[6, 13, 10, 20, 24],
 [2, 14, 16, 21, 19],
 [0, 8, 17, 15, 5],
 [3, 18, 7, 12, 23],
 [22, 1, 4, 9, 11]]
```

**UPDATE:** to remove the "sequencing" problem, this is a possible solution:

```
import random
import pprint

number_rows_columns = 20
matrix_is_valid = False

def fill_matrix():
    number_list = [i for i in range(number_rows_columns**2)]
    matrix = []
    for row in range(number_rows_columns):
        new_column = []
        for column in range(number_rows_columns):
            new_column.append(random.choice(number_list))
            number_list.remove(new_column[-1])
        matrix.append(new_column)
    return matrix

def check_rows(matrix):
    global matrix_is_valid
    for row in matrix:
        for index, element in enumerate(row[:-1]):
            if abs(element - row[index + 1]) == 1:
                matrix_is_valid = False
                return

def check_matrix(matrix):
    global matrix_is_valid
    matrix_is_valid = True
    check_rows(matrix)
    if not matrix_is_valid:
        return
    matrix = list(list(a) for a in zip(*matrix))
    check_rows(matrix)


while not matrix_is_valid:
    final_matrix = fill_matrix()
    check_matrix(final_matrix)

pprint.pprint(final_matrix)
```

**IMPORTANT:** I would like to specify that **this is NOT an efficient solution**. Basically this algorithm create a matrix, check that each row and column (by transposition) has no numbers "sequencing", and if there are any, create a new matrix and check that until he gets a valid one.
This is an algorithm that has an average time complexity of `O((n+1)!)`, see [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) to deepen.

**UPDATE IMPROVED VERSION:** This improved version check the validity of each number insertion, so, the matrix must be rebuilt from scratch only if and when the last number cannot be entered

**The code:**

```
import random
import pprint

number_rows_columns = 12
matrix_is_valid = False
counter = 0

def fill_matrix():
    global matrix_is_valid
    matrix_is_valid = True
    number_list = [i for i in range(number_rows_columns**2)]
    matrix = []
    for row in range(number_rows_columns):
        new_column = []
        for column in range(number_rows_columns):
            new_column.append(random.choice(number_list))
            if (column > 0 or row > 0) and len(number_list) > 1:
                invalid_value = True
                if column != 0 and row != 0:
                    while abs(new_column[-1] - new_column[-2]) == 1 or abs(new_column[-1] - matrix[-1][column]) == 1:
                        new_column[-1] = random.choice(number_list)
                elif column != 0 and row == 0:
                    while abs(new_column[-1] - new_column[-2]) == 1:
                        new_column[-1] = random.choice(number_list)
                elif column == 0 and row != 0:
                    while abs(new_column[-1] - matrix[-1][column]) == 1:
                        new_column[-1] = random.choice(number_list)
            number_list.remove(new_column[-1])
        matrix.append(new_column)
    if abs(matrix[-1][-1] - matrix[-1][-2]) == 1 or abs(matrix[-1][-1] - matrix[-2][-1]) == 1:
        matrix_is_valid = False
    return matrix


while not matrix_is_valid:
    final_matrix = fill_matrix()

pprint.pprint(final_matrix)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. but in some cases, the sequencing is still happening. It seems I should consider what value I must append to new_column

Comment: @Dreyar Sorry me but what do you mean by "the sequencing is sill happening"? Have you had problems with this code? It works correctly for me by assigning any value to `number_rows_columns`

Comment: sorry for my unclear.  I mean on several occasions, there's a sequence of 2 numbers (maybe more) in a single row/column (i.e: [12, 11, ....]). But now I am thinking a possible solution to check every row and column with for loop if there's any, i will resuffle those row/column with while loops.

Comment: @Dreyar I understand, I'm sorry I hadn't thought about that problem, I'll think about it for a moment and I warn you when solved

Comment: @Dreyar I have updated the answer with a possible solution to your problem!

Comment: Thank you so much, I just finished my own. Maybe you can review my code for improvement.

Comment: @Dreyar I read your solution. Our solutions are equivalent. I'm working to improve my solution so that the matrix is checked at the insertion of each value, so that it has to be restarted from zero only in case it is not possible to insert the last element (do I make myself clear?). Note that in term of efficiency this is not even comparable

Comment: @Dreyar I've updated the answer again. This time the final cose is much much more efficient (I've tested for 100 squared matrix and have never taken more than 2 attempts to build a valid matrix)